# How to update a record from index in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, devise, edit

I was trying to update a User record (only the "closed" named column) from the user index's view. This is what I tried. But, it is not working. I used Devise gem to generate views and controllers. But, whatever, How can I update a records one particular value, directly from index(without going to edit's view). It would be very helpful, if someone would help me.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
                <tr>
                  <td> <%= user.last_name %></td>
                  <td> <%= user.telephone %></td>
                  <td> <%= form_for user do |f| %>
                    <% if user.closed %>
                      <%= f.hidden_field :closed, value: false %>
                      <%= f.submit "Activate" %>
                      <% else %>
                        <%= f.hidden_field :closed, value: true %>
                        <%= f.submit "Deactivate" %>
                      <% end %>
                  <% end %> </td>
                      <%= link_to 'Remove', user_destroy_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def user_index
    if current_user.admin?
      if params[:user_search].present?
        @users = User.search_user(params[:user_search]).super_admin
      else
        @users = User.super_admin
      end
    else
      if params[:user_search].present?
        @users = User.search_user(params[:user_search]).admin
      else
        @users = User.admin
      end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data User.to_csv, type: 'text/csv', filename: "users.csv" }
    end
  end
```

here is my controller. Actually there is also something done to search the users

Comment: Yeah, I also tried that, it shows this following error:   "undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f50ec165488>:0x007f50fe208e78>
Did you mean?  users_path"

Comment: Your controller

Comment: post your controller

Comment: controller given

Comment: Your controller name?

Comment: class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

Comment: i am posted answer  its helpful?

Comment: Checking bro. After finishing, I will give you an upvote and also mark your answer as accepted. Don't worry

Comment: ok bro but its working me!..Ask me if your facing any error?

Comment: ok bro, I had to moderate something for my code. But, thanks a lot, your code.

Comment: By the way bro, If I want to pass some parameter with this, do you know, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, create two methods `activate` and `deactivate`.

In controller,

```
 def activate
    @user = User.find_by(:id=>params[:id])
    @user.update(:closed=>false)
    redirect_to #your path
  end

  def deactivate
    @user = User.find_by(:id=>params[:id])
    @user.update(:closed=>true)
    redirect_to #your path
  end
```

Set your routes as,

```
patch '#yourcontroller/:id/activate',to:'#yourcontroller#activate' , as: :activate
patch '#yourcontroller/:id/deactivate',to:'#yourcontroller#deactivate' ,as: :deactivate
```

and finally do changes in your view as,

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
           <tr>
             <td> <%= user.last_name %></td>
             <td> <%= user.telephone %></td>
             <td> <%if user.closed?%>
                  <%= link_to 'activate',activate_path(id:user.id), method: :patch%>
                 <%else%>  
                  <%= link_to 'deactivate',deactivate_path(id:user.id), method: :patch%>
                  <% end -%> </td>
                  <%= link_to 'Remove', user_destroy_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
```

Its helpful pls up-vote!

Comment: _Its helpful pls up-vote!_ ? Do not beg for votes ever in answer where you are not assured whether it helped OP or not also.